# Why an up arrow in git branch icon in visual studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2022 (17.0.2) Enterprise Edition. I See up arrow in some git branch icons as shown in the image. What is the meaning of it? The branches in the image have the latest code and there are no local changes to push as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I've found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/exciting-new-updates-to-the-git-experience-in-visual-studio/) and then confirmed on my own, those with an arrow are tracking a remote branch, and the others are purely local branches.

In Visual Studio, go to the Git menu and select Manage Branches.

Then on the left, mouse over those branches to display a popup/tooltip/hint. The ones with the arrow should have a property called Tracked Branch.

Comment: And if you want to make a purely local branch to be trackable, simply right click on it and select push, that will make it a trackable green up arrow branch.